# Optimizing CSS Delivery in Theme

Tags: theming, 8

I ran my site through [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and got the following message:

**Optimize CSS delivery of the following:**

**First** it lists two CSS files I don't recognize in /sites/default/files

**Second**, it lists my font awesome css which I'm LINKING to from my `.libraries.yml` file, like so:

```
font-awesome:
  remote: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
  version: 4.5.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/
    gpl-compatible: true
  css:
    theme:
      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css: { type: external, minified: true }
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js: {}
```

**So my question then is two-fold:**

Short of using another module such as [Addvagg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg)

1) How can I speed up delivery of the font awesome css?

2) What are those other CSS files and how can I speed up delivery of them?

Answer (score -1):

1. download the font & css files, don't use a cdn
2. minify and concat your css, additionally you can use sass & gulp to
   do the job for you

Comment: Could you explain how these actions will help? Drupal already concats and minifies (aggregates) CSS so using gulp for the same thing seems redundant doesn't it? Also serving content from a CDN means the user may already have the file in cache and not need to download it, helps to reduce the number of simultaneous requests the browser has to make to the website domain, and typically does so without cookie/session overhead, thus improving page load times and server load. Why would manually hosting and serving files that can be statically served from a CDN yield an improvement?

Comment: It could be that the cdn is slowing your site down.

Comment: Or it could just as easily be speeding it up...

Comment: you will have to investigate....